# Collections.sort(List<T>) not applicable for HashSet<Book>

Tags: java, collections, hashset, comparable

I have created a `HashSet` which contains elements of type `Book(name, author)`. I have implemented the `Comparable` interface. But calling `Collections.sort()` results an error.

> The method `sort(List<T>)` in the type `Collections` is not applicable for the arguments (`HashSet<Book>`)

Here is an example where book elements added  as below

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashSet;
public class BookHashSetDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashSet<Book> hashSet=new HashSet<Book>();
        Book book1=new Book("ABC","XYZ");
        Book book2=new Book("lmn","opq");
        Book book3=new Book("rst","uvw");
        Book book4=new Book("ABC","XYZ");

        hashSet.add(book1);
        hashSet.add(book2);
        hashSet.add(book3);
        hashSet.add(book4);

        System.out.println(hashSet);
        Book book=new Book();
        Collections.sort(hashSet);
    }
```

And this is the class `Book` where `Comparable` is implemented as below

```
class Book implements Comparable<Book> {
    String name;
    String author;

    public Book(String name, String author) {
        this.name=name;
        this.author=author;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return author+"-->"+name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Book o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return name.compareTo(o.name);
    }
}
```

What I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Collections.sort` method accepts only `List<T>`, but you are trying to pass a `Set` to it.

Comment: You can't sort a HashSet. You can use a TreeSet, and then the Set will be sorted.

Comment: @Oleksandr even if it's that simple, it counts as an answer IMO

Answer (score 2):

[`Collections.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort-java.util.List-) accepts a `List`, but you are trying to pass a `Set` to it, thus an error occurs.

According to the example given in the question, it's better to use a [`TreeSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html):

```
Set<Book> books = new TreeSet<>();
```

And, if the `Book` class implements `Comparable<Book>` interface, then you can just write:

```
books.add(new Book("DEF", "XYZ"));
books.add(new Book("ABC", "XYZ");
```

`TreeSet` elements will be ordered according to the `Book.compareTo(...)` method implementation.